# OFFSET with SQL Server 2008R2 doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have around 24000000 revisions in my table, but when I try to get just between 1 and 100 rows, the query take a lot of time.

I try to use `OFFSET` and because it's not the same on SQL Server 2008 R2 like SQL Server 2012.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(rev_date AS varchar) Rev_Date, 
    CAST(username AS varchar) UserName,
    CAST(rev AS varchar) Rev,  
    CAST(rev_type AS varchar) Rev_Type,
    CAST(id_cl AS varchar) id, 
    CAST(id_ AS varchar) abstract,
    CAST(id AS varchar) participant, 
    CAST(id_ref_decl_channel AS varchar) refDecChannel,
    CAST(old_sherpa_number AS varchar) oldSherpaNumber, 
    CAST(is_notifier AS varchar) notify, 
    CAST(is_declarer AS varchar) declarer, 
    CAST(dispatch_rate AS varchar) dispatchRate 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         CAST(inf.rev_date AS varchar) Rev_Date, 
         CAST(inf.username AS varchar) UserName,
         CAST(aud.rev AS varchar) Rev,  
         CAST(aud.rev_type AS varchar) Rev_Type,
         CAST(aud.id_cl AS varchar) id, 
         CAST(aud.id_ AS varchar) abstract,
         CAST(aud.id AS varchar) participant, 
         CAST(aud.id_ref_decl_channel AS varchar) refDecChannel,
         CAST(aud.old_sherpa_number AS varchar) oldSherpaNumber, 
         CAST(aud.is_notifier AS varchar) notify,
         CAST(aud.is_declarer AS varchar) declarer, 
         CAST(aud.dispatch_rate AS varchar) dispatchRate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SalesOrderDetailID) AS RowNum
     FROM 
         oth_aud aud, ref.rev_info inf 
     WHERE 
         aud.rev = inf.id_rev_info AND aud.rev_type = 0) AS SOD
WHERE 
    SOD.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

I would like by using this principle of offset , to use the pagination in my web page.

I know that there are a lot of solution like datatable for jQuery but me I want using SQL Server.

Have any propositions?

Comment: `OFFSET` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** .....

Comment: First of all - ***why*** are you casting everything **twice**? If you're casting in the inner `SELECT` - there's absolutely **no point** in casting *again* in the outer `SELECT`. Also: when casting, please **always** specify a **length** for the `VARCHAR` !! Do you know what the default is? Maybe you were lucky and never got anything truncated - but it's just good common sense to **define a length** like this: `CAST(.... AS VARCHAR(50))`

Comment: i use the cast because i work with JPA and there is no dialect for SQLserver for some type that's why i have to cast all but doen't cause a problem

Comment: `CAST` is okay - *once*, but not **TWICE**!

Comment: What is your question actually? You have working code and OFFSET is not available on SQL 2008.

Comment: My question is as i saif above : why that type of query whitch writen above is so slow for execution and there is a way to improuve it *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OFFSET exists in SQL Server 2012